# Puedo aplicarle Skin de Devexpress a un formulario de Visual Studio, C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Se puede poner la opcion de cambio de Skin de Devexpress en un formulario de visual studio, es algo asi.[image: Esto a un Form]

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes hacerlo

[How to: Populate a Menu and a Ribbon Gallery with Localized Skin Items](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8883)

[How to: Get a List of Available Skins](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument14360)

En el primer link explica como poder listar los skin en un ribbon

En el segundo recorrer los skin habilitados

```
foreach(SkinContainer cnt in SkinManager.Default.Skins) {
    comboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.Add(cnt.SkinName);
}
```

para cargar alguna lista o combo.

Comment: Leandro era justo lo que buscava, mil gracias, quisiera saber si puedo agregar mas temas al combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he encontrado, al cargar los Skins debo poner:

```
DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
```